# incremental http live streaming

Tags: http, video, streaming, http-live-streaming

I seek to use the http live streaming standard with video. I'd like to eliminate any delay while a user is working with our app, but the current architecture requires fully encoding audio with any new or removed video clips.

Is there an incremental encoding approach to http live streaming so that I can

1. keep the audio track separate, but playback seamlessly with the video stream
2. allows .ts chunks to be independently encoded and streamed back to a user faster than re-encoding an entire video

References:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: What is your target platform(s)?

Comment: @StuThompson Why would the target platform matter? He's trying to follow a standard, the platform MUST be irrelevant.

Comment: @vipw: keeping the audio tracks *"separate"* (as in separate streams, I read) yet sync'd will require some fancy footwork.  Probably not possible with most platforms, unless he has a lot of control over the target.  It sounds like he has some non-trivial de/re/muxing going on.

Comment: @StuThompson Ah, I see what you mean. I think he's just overlooking the ability to remux instead of re-encode.

Comment: @StuThompson linux ubuntu. vipw I'd like them to play back together, and be controlled by the same video interface. Thanks for the tip Stu on remux'ing, that could be faster. I have long term and short term goals and it's helpful to know and plan for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-encode the required segments fairly easily -- there's no need to have the entire stream encoded before playing it (otherwise live events would be impossible). You have to be careful with the timestamps in the TS packets if you want it to be truly seamless. But what might be easiest is to use `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` markers around the re-created portions.

As for audio, there's no need to re-encode it. You should be able to just copy the encoded audio from one TS container to another. For example, if you're using ffmpeg, you would use `-acodec copy` to take it from the original ts.

Comment: So let's say a video segment is dropped (the first one), and another is added. Current processing re-encodes the entire video. How would copying music work, since it has changed for many/all the videos?